# set a value in controller using angularjs $routeprovider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I don't have any clue on how I should implement this problem. I have to mention 2 issue which I faced with:
**First** When I implement my web application, I was unaware of ng-view functionalities. So I implement my web page using parent/child controller manner. I control showing the nested controllers using parent controller. in other word, I didn't use ng-view and template.
**Second** I want to navigate to a nested controller when the page is loaded.
As an example of my website, the user may redirected to a url like http://mywebsite/#SpecificSection:SomeParameter. The following sample codes shows how my web application display content:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {

    })
        .when('/profile', 
        //load user profile and set isChild2Active to true
        );
});
app.controller('parentController', ['$scope',  function ($scope) {
    $scope.isChild1Active = true;
    $scope.isChild2Active = false;
}]);

<div ng-controller="parentController">
<div ng-controller="child1Controller" ng-show="isChild1Active"></div>
<div ng-controller="child2Controller" ng-show="isChild2Active">
    for example a specific user profile
</div>
```

I want to write piece of code which initialize the nested controller with the correct values and display that controller.
As I saw in examples, $routeProvider set the controller and template. So **I didn't find a solution which initialize a variable using $routeProvider**. Is there any solution which solve the problem?

Comment: Exactly what you want to do ? Some code will help to solve problem.

Comment: is my explain enough, or you want more details?